# c:\Program Files\Java\glassfish 4\glassfish\domains\domain1 Not writable

Tags: java, windows, glassfish, java-8, eclipse-kepler

I am working on eclipse kepler with jdk 1.8.0_20 and windows 8.1 Operating System. I choose location for glassfish 4 and click next and it gives me
c:\Program Files\Java\glassfish 4\glassfish\domains\domain1 is not writable

I tried answer given in stackoverflow but did not get the  solution I think i.e given for Linux. I tried almost all the things given in all the site , But I did not get the solution. Plz somebody answer me.Thank u In advance

Comment: What answer did you try? Provide a link. You can check the folder permissions if it is indeed not writable.

Answer (score 10):

Folder "Program Files" in c: drive has restricted access, instead of installing Glassfish server in "Program Files" try installing out of it. Or try running eclipse as "Run as administrator". Better is to install Glassfish somewhere else from "Program Files".

Comment: Thank U Nagesh Kumar for answering the Question. It is working fine when I moved it to C: drive.